# Как установить цвет заднего фона Label в kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Только начал изучать kivy. И вот возник вопрос. А как установить цвет в label? В pyqt это делается в два счета. Тем более не понятно, как это сделать в .kv файле, ведь именно там создается label? В общем, не понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Label:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .5, .5, .5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

canvas доступен для любого виджета kivy.